# VB 2010, Complex numbers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Hi does anybody know if is possible to utilise formulas containing complex numbers within basic programming. Part of the formula im trying to implement is i(e^2-e^2-2), e represents exponential and i the imaginary number. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Start by googling "vb.net complex numbers".  The first hit is already good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to the **System.Numerics** library to your project (Go to MyProject->References->Add->Assemblies->Search the list for `System.Numerics`). You can also import the namespace in your source by using `Imports System.Numerics`.

In this library you can find functions to compute complex numbers.

You define a complex number for example with the line

```
Dim MyComplex as New Complex(Realpart, ImaginaryPart)
```

To compute the exponential you would use

```
Dim Exped as Complex = Complex.Exp(MyComplex)
```

and so on. There are functions for most operations and the complex numbers support general operators like +, -, *, / as well.

For your specific problem you would just use

```
Dim result as New Complex(0, Math.Exp(2)-Math.Exp(2)-2)
```

This works because i*x is a complex number with a real part of zero and an imaginary part of x. I'm not judging how much sense your definition makes :-)

Comment: thanks very much for your input and taking the time to respond, very helpful in understanding to add the systems.numeric file etc..the calculation is part of a much larger algorithm. If I input the above calculation into a calculator it provides an answer of 7.25i, I am trying to replicate this but do not seem to be able to achieve this with the above code, am I to expand upon this?

Comment: e^2-e^2-2 is just -2. Maybe you have typo in the code you provided. What exactly did you type into your calculator?

Comment: ive got it to display the value i wanted now struggling to get it to display the imaginary number 'i',  perhaps it may be of more use to upload the full algorithm

Comment: People can't answer more than what you ask. If you further explain your problem, then people can provide more extensive answers.